# Foreign key returns null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, foreign-keys

iam working on my first database in postgresql and I am stuck with a problem I cannot solve. After implementing the database, I started inserting dummy data via data.csv files. After doing i realized that my foreign keys always return null. For example the foreign key from the table fact_werbepartner references to the primary key dim_ansprechpartner.

My desired is that the foreign key inherits the primary key numbers so I can JOIN tables!

When selecting dim_ansprechpartner get the following information:
[return values dim_ansprechpartner]
[image: 1]

When selecting fact_werbepartner I get these null references:
[return values fact_werbepartner]
[image: 2]

FYI: When I add the NOT NULL Constraint, I get the following error message: column "wp_ansprechpartner_fk" of relation "fact_werbepartner" contains null values ( which is kinda obvious..)

Stuck with this problem for hours! How can I solve it?

[CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H_reY-b2pn9PiBbU0gGRGKBxipW8QJIR?usp=sharing)

[ERD Diagramm two tables]
[image: 4]

[ERD DIAGRAMM complete database]
[image: 5]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim_ansprechpartner(
    ap_partner_id_pk serial NOT NULL,
    ap_partnername varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ap_Telefonnummer  varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ap_partner_id_pk)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fact_werbepartner(
    wp_firmen_id_pk  serial NOT NULL,
    wp_firmenname varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    wp_firmengroesse int,
    wp_ansprechpartner_fk int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (wp_firmen_id_pk),
    FOREIGN KEY (wp_ansprechpartner_fk)
        REFERENCES dim_ansprechpartner(ap_partner_id_pk)
    
);
COPY dim_ansprechpartner(ap_Partnername, ap_Telefonnummer)
FROM 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\mock data\dim_ansprechpartner.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER;

COPY fact_werbepartner(wp_firmenname,wp_firmengroesse)
FROM 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\mock data\fact_werbepartner.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: What is the source csv files loading the tables? Can you share their content?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H_reY-b2pn9PiBbU0gGRGKBxipW8QJIR?usp=sharing, you can view them there. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try changing the data type for the foreign key to int type in the second table as well?

Comment: yes i did tried both int and bigint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` establishes a relationship between two tables and you don't have that. When you do `COPY dim_ansprechpartner(ap_Partnername, ap_Telefonnummer)` the `ap_partner_id_pk` is going to be automatically filled with integers. Each time you do that it will be an incremented set of numbers unless you reset the sequence behind the `serial` type. In any case when you do `COPY fact_werbepartner(wp_firmenname,wp_firmengroesse)` the `wp_ansprechpartner_fk` field will not be filled in, hence the `NULLs` you see. Since that is the FK to `dim_ansprechpartner` there will be no relationship. You at some point need to make that relationship explicit. Either by adding `ap_partner_id_pk` in `dim_ansprechpartner.csv` and `wp_ansprechpartner_fk` in `fact_werbepartner.csv` or by some other means. Postgres has no way of establishing that otherwise.

Comment: Thank you i had thought that the foreign key can auto populate the data given by the primary key. It makes sense that it doesnt, because the child cant know which parent its belongs to. I think its best to just insert the columns of the dimension into the fact table, as my goal would only result in a unique one to unique one relationship. If iam not wrong please correct me.

Comment: Since `ap_partner_id_pk` is a `SERIAL` column you will either need to populate `dim_ansprechpartner` first and grab the numbers to use in `fact_werbepartner.wp_ansprechpartner_fk` or pre-populate both in the CSV's. If you pre populate `ap_partner_id_pk` value you will need to  `ALTER SEQUENCE the_sequence RESTART some_number` where some_number is `MAX(ap_partner_id_pk) +1`.